# Como apagar a linha no memo de acordo com a quantidades de Numeros em Delphi?

Tags: string, delphi, pascal, delphi-xe8

Boa Noite, tenho um memo que recebe varias strings e em muitas linhas, quero apagar as linhas que contém menos ou mais de sete(7) números ,deixando apenas as linhas que tenha exatamente sete(7) números
estou tentando com um código só que todo Memo é apagado.

```
var
cont, N: Integer;
begin
cont:= 0;
N := Length(GetStrNumber(Memo2.Lines.Strings[cont])); //N = quantidade de 
//números na linha no Memo

while (cont <= Memo2.Lines.Count  - 1)  do
if N <> 7 then  //Se N é diferente de 7 então apagar a linha

begin
Memo2.Lines.Delete(cont)
end

else
Inc(cont);
```

Answer (score 1):

O N que você esta usando para validar esta fora do laço que faz a interação.
Tente assim:

```
procedure ApagaLinhas;
var
cont, N: Integer;
begin
  cont:= 0;

  while (cont <= Memo1.Lines.Count  - 1)  do
  begin
    N := Length(GetStrNumber(Memo1.Lines.Strings[cont])); //N = quantidade de
    //números na linha no Memo
    if N <> 7 then  //Se N é diferente de 7 então apagar a linha
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Delete(cont)
    end else
    begin
      Inc(cont);
    end;
  end;
end;
```